# Adding values to a C# array from a different class

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I'm trying to add new values input by the user on a separate windows form into the following array:

```
public class NameValue
  {
    public string Name;
    public string Value;
    public NameValue() { Name = null; Value = null; }
    public NameValue(string name, string value) { Name = name; Value = value; }
  }

   public class DefaultSettings
  {
    public static NameValue[] Sites = new NameValue[] 
    {
        new NameValue("los angeles, CA", "http://losangeles.craigslist.org/"),
    };

    public static NameValue[] Categories = new NameValue[] 
    {
        new NameValue("all for sale", "sss"),
    };
   }
```

How do I add the new values to the array while keeping the values of the old array?

**Edit**

I tried using Mr. Noren's function:

```
        static void AddValueToSites(NameValue newValue)
    {
        int size = DefaultSettings.Sites.Length;
        NameValue[] newSites = new NameValue[size + 1];
        Array.Copy(DefaultSettings.Sites, newSites, size);
        newSites[size] = newValue;
        DefaultSettings.Sites = newSites;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NameValue newSite = new NameValue("Test, OR", "http://portland.craigslist.org/"); 
        AddValueToSites(newSite);
        Close();
    }
```

But that's not working... The class I am getting data from is:

```
public partial class Location : Office2007Form
{
    public Location()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    static void AddValueToSites(NameValue newValue)...
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)...
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an array instead of a mutable collection like `List<T>`?

Comment: If you want to add elements, an array is not the proper construct.  As @M.Babcock suggested, something that implements `IList<T>` would be a much more appropriate strategy.

Comment: What class do you want to add values from?

Comment: What's the specific problem? Is it that it is too protected? You may need to decorate with protected, internal or public on the static void Add... functions.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot change the size of an array, ever. You would need to use something like a `List` for that.

Since you're using name/value pairs you should consider using `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.

Finally, if you're looking to have different classes contribute to the contents of the arrays, then that's not going to happen.

Answer (score 4):

You can't add to an array, whether it's in another class or not.

Use `List<NameValue>` instead of `NameValue[]` and then you can use `Sites.Add(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're absolutely married to the idea of using an array versus some more flexible collection, you should implement some AddX() methods in the class that is defining the base values. Those methods would take care of inserting the new values in the array. If you're not concerned with multithreading issues, it can be very simple:

(Warning: code is from my head and not tested)

```
static void AddValueToSites(NameValue newValue)
{
    int size = Sites.Length;
    NameValue[] newSites = new NameValue[size+1];
    Array.Copy(Sites, newSites, size);
    newSites[size] = newValue;
    Sites = newSites;
}
```

And again for Categories.

Like others suggested, using `List<NameValue>` or `Dictionary<string,string>` would be options that would be more fluid. These already have Add, Remove, Contains, etc. - basically all you need when you need to manipulate arrays.

Comment: Wow thanks guys! So, how would I use your function?  `private void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  {  NameValue newSite = new NameValue(textBox1.Text,textBox2.Text);    
            AddValueToSites(newSite);    
            Close();
        }`

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not mutable in place, so if you resize them (using any approach) it'll result in a different instance being created (this is what happens in VB.NET's `ReDim` but they hide it from you).

The simplest way to resize an array in C# is to use the `Concat` extension method (requires `System.Linq`):

```
string[] myArray = new string[] { "Hello", "World" };
myArray = myArray.Concat(new string[] { "Something", "new" };
```

`myArray` will now be 4 elements deep. I don't think this will work between classes though (haven't tried though).